# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles slow when using SearchOption.AllDirectories

Tags: .net, performance, file-io

I am searching a moderate number (~500) of folders for a large number (~200,000) of files from a .NET application.

I hoped to use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`, passing in `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. However this approach seems to be a lot slower than writing my own code to iterate through the directories and do `GetFiles` just passing in a `searchPattern`.

Related [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx):

- `GetFiles(String)`
  Returns a file list from the current directory matching the given searchPattern.
- `GetFiles(String, SearchOption)`
  Returns a file list from the current directory matching the given searchPattern and using a value to determine whether to search subdirectories.

Has anyone had a similar experience to this?

Comment: The time it takes for `GetFiles()` to return, can be estimated with the File Explorer context menu for Properties. On a folder with lots of subfolders it may take "forever" to show the total number of files/folders/bytes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These two functions are actually infamous for their performance. The reason is that `GetFiles` walks entire directory tree and constructs an array of `FileInfo` objects, and only then returns the result to the caller. Construction of said array involves a lot of memory allocations (I'm sure they use `List` internally, but still) since the number of entries cannot be known ahead of time.

If you're really into performance, you can P/Invoke into [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx)/[FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx)/[FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx), abstract them into an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` and `yield` `FileInfo`s one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

The approach Anton mentioned using `FindFirstFile()` and related native methods has been implemented as of .NET 4 via `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` so no more need for P/Invoke for this!